# Is there a way to refactor this javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, case, switch-statement

```
switch (options.effect) {

case 'h-blinds-fadein':
    $('.child').each(function(i) {
        $(this).stop().css({
            opacity: 0
        }).delay(100 * i).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, {
            duration: options.speed,
            complete: (i !== r * c - 1) ||
            function() {
                $(this).parent().replaceWith(prev);
                options.cp.bind('click', {
                    effect: options.effect
                }, options.ch);
            }
        });
    });

    break;

case 'h-blinds-fadein-reverse':
    $('.child').each(function(i) {
        $(this).stop().css({
            opacity: 0
        }).delay(100 * (r * c - i)).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, {
            duration: options.speed,
            complete: (i !== 0) ||
            function() {
                $(this).parent().replaceWith(prev);
                options.cp.bind('click', {
                    effect: options.effect
                }, options.ch);
            }
        });
    });

    break;

    ....more cases
}
```

I have alot of similiar other cases. One way i could think of is to write functions ? i'm not sure i'm still fairly new to the language

im sorry, i is the index of the each() function which is the size of $('.child'), and r and c are just the 'rows' and 'columns' of the grid which contains '.child'.
r and c can be any number, e.g. r=5 c=5

Comment: @JeffAtwood at least move it to codereview.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather then using a switch, store the case specific data in a hash.

Then run the main block of code and extract anything effect type specific from the hash.

```
function doit(e) {
    var hash = {
        'h-blinds-fadein': {
            delay: function(i) { return i; },
            complete: function(i) { return (i !== r * c - 1); }
        },
        'h-blinds-fadein-reverse': {
            delay: function(i) { return (r * c - i); },
            complete: function(i) { return i !== 0; }
        }
    }

    $('.child').each(function(i) {
        $(this).stop().css({
            opacity: 0
        }).delay(100 * hash[e].delay(i)).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, {
            duration: options.speed,
            complete: hash[e].complete(i) ||
            function() {
                $(this).parent().replaceWith(prev);
                options.cp.bind('click', {
                    effect: options.effect
                }, options.ch);
            }
        });
    });
}

doit(options.effect);
```

Comment: Thanks Raynos. I'm not sure if this is too localized, but to me, Raynos showed the way how object orient programming should really be done.

Comment: @whyzee I don't think it is. It might belong on codereview.SE though

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what i, r and c are, it's very hard to refactor. This can be condensed to a function passing those numbers as variables - as ultimately all the other parts of the code are the same.

Comment: im sorry, i is the index of the each() function which is the size of $('.child'), and r and c are just the 'rows' and 'columns' of the grid which contains '.child'. r and c can be any number, e.g. r=5 c=5

Answer (score 0):

I think using a `function` in each of the case statements would be the first thing to do.

```
case 'h-blinds-fadein':
    hBlindsFadeIn(options);    
    break;

...

function hBlindsFadeIn(options){
       $('.child').each(function(i) {
            $(this).stop().css({
                opacity: 0
            }).delay(100 * i).animate({
                'opacity': 1
            }, {
                duration: options.speed,
                complete: (i !== r * c - 1) ||
                function() {
                    $(this).parent().replaceWith(prev);
                    options.cp.bind('click', {
                        effect: options.effect
                    }, options.ch);
                }
            });
        });
}
```

Obviously your function would need to be outside of the switch.

Comment: Actually forget my answer, @Raynos has the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

All I could suggest would be to refactor the actual effects into separate methods, this would make your switch statement a bit more readable, i.e.:

```
switch (options.effect) {

case 'h-blinds-fadein':
    h-blinds-fadein();
    break;

case 'h-blinds-fadein-reverse':
    h-blinds-fadein-reverse();
    break;

    ....more cases
}

function h-blinds-fadein() {
    $('.child').each(function(i) {
        $(this).stop().css({
            opacity: 0
        }).delay(100 * i).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, {
            duration: options.speed,
            complete: (i !== r * c - 1) ||
            function() {
                $(this).parent().replaceWith(prev);
                options.cp.bind('click', {
                    effect: options.effect
                }, options.ch);
            }
        });
    });
}

function h-blinds-fadein-reverse() {
    $('.child').each(function(i) {
        $(this).stop().css({
            opacity: 0
        }).delay(100 * (r * c - i)).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, {
            duration: options.speed,
            complete: (i !== 0) ||
            function() {
                $(this).parent().replaceWith(prev);
                options.cp.bind('click', {
                    effect: options.effect
                }, options.ch);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Alternatively you could try the `eval` function with the refactored functions thus:

```
eval(options.effect+"();");
```

---- EDIT ----

Love Raynos refactoring, this could also be incorporated.

Comment: -1 for recommending eval. Just recommend `window[options.effect]()` instead.

Comment: @Raynos : Explain to us (for the OPs benefit) why eval is evil in this context.

Comment: If the functions are global then `window[options.effect]()` is faster by a few orders of magnitude. Eval is just generally overkill and should be avoided at all costs. It would be better to save the functions in a hash then call `hash[options.effect]()`. It kills performance and it's a right pain to debug.

Comment: @Raynos : Now the OP knows why ;) Good explanation.

Comment: @Lazarus unless you still feel using eval is valid you can remove the eval recommendation and people can undo the down votes.

Comment: @Raynos: I agree that eval isn't the optimal way but I would hope the downvote would cause people to read this and the comments and learn something so I'm happy to leave and for you to leave the downvote :)

Comment: @Lazarus I would think it's better to re-factor the comments into your answer though. People are more likely to read them then to read the comments. but that's really a meta discussion, you might want to bring it up on meta.SO